# Is it possible to do multi-line commits with GitAhead

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, gitea, gitahead

I currently used **GitAhead** as my primary GUI for interfacing git source control. My question is if it is possible to support multi-line commits messages with **GitAhead**?

My first thought is there might be a way to amend the default config file to change the commit button's git command or add a sequence of commands, such as `git commit -f [file]` or `git commit -m "Short Message"` and then after that run `git commit --amend`.

If this isn't possible, then is the only option to modify source code since it is open source? I believe the most likely case is I am just missing a configuration setting that is possible.

Comment: You should be able to write multiline commit messages by just pressing Enter in the commit message editor. Do you mean something different?

Comment: I am writing multi-line but they are always showing up as a single line of text on the commit on my local repo and on the remote server repo @JasonHaslam

Comment: I've never seen anything like that. Just to be clear, are you adding explicit line breaks by pressing Enter?

Comment: Yes. It is worth noting we host our backend repo on a Linux server. Maybe it is line break conversions? @JasonHaslam

Comment: For the record, GitAhead development has been stopped. The Gittyup fork has successfully taken the succession: https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write multi-line commit messages with GitAhead.

You have to let a blank line between the short summary and the long description.

Here is a screenshot of GitAhead 2.6.3 ready to commit a multi-line message:

[image]

Comment: FI, GitAhead is deprecated and has been replaced by https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup.